# logical OR condition not working as expected

Tags: boolean-logic

In my Decision class, I have 3 conditional statement like below:

GeneralCondition class contains promptUser(user).

```
class Decision extends GeneralCondition{
    private boolean hasChildrens(User user){
        return user.getHaveChilds();
    }

    private boolean hasSpouse(User user){
        return user.getHaveSpouse();
    }

    private boolean newUser(User user){
        return user.isNewUser();
    }

    boolean interruptUser(User user){
        boolean hasChildrens=boolean hasChildrens(User user);
        boolean hasSpouse= boolean hasSpouse(User user);
        boolean newUser= newUser(User user);
        return hasChildrens||hasSpouse||newUser;
    }
}
```

//Below is the class caalling interruptUser():

class UserCondition extends GeneralCondition{

GeneralCondition gcon=new GeneralCondition();

if(gcon.interruptUser(user)){

//redirect to condition PopUp Flow;

}

else

{

//redirect to Home Page;

}

}

`interruptUser(user)` is called by other object. When I use all 3 condition as above every time it returns False, even if it is true; and when I use only 2 condition it works as expected.  Please suggest what could be reason.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: it is in Java1.5

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to test this program with the Java programming language. The problem is that your code is not correct and will never compile, most likely.

Comment: Where is your driver class? what about the User class definition?

Comment: You need to paste all your source files, including the driver to find out where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The function needs to have a User object passed in, and then pass that object to each of the test functions that needs it.

```
boolean interruptUser(User user){
    boolean hasChildrens = hasChildrens(user);
    boolean hasSpouse = hasSpouse(user);
    boolean newUser = newUser(user);
    return hasChildrens || hasSpouse || newUser;
}
```

Comment: its same the way u have written. i just missed while posting. but result is always false when i use all three.  and when try with 2 condition  its working fine.

Comment: It sounds like you typed your code in instead of copying and pasting it in. Please copy and paste the EXACT code in, otherwise we waste time figuring out where you messed up :)